# Can't Show JOptionPane - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog

I am new to Java. And I need your help.

My code is working well until it shows `JDialog`. I have a button to show a message dialog (`JOptionPane`). The problem exist when the button is clicked. Message dialog doesn't seems to appear. It more like stuck, can't be closed and it must be terminated from my Eclipse.

Please anyone tell me why `JOptionPane` can't show? And I don't know what the meaning of `parentComponent` on its parameter.

Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private JButton testPane = new JButton(" Test Pane ");

    Test() {

        initComp();

    }

    private void initComp() {

        this.setSize(300, 200);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);

        testPane.setBounds(47, 25, 200, 120);
        this.add(testPane);
        testPane.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Does it show?");

    }

}
```

Comment: Avoid  using `setLayout (null)` unless it's badly needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to add the following statement in `initComp` so that the `JFrame` gets visible:

```
private void initComp() {
    ...
    this.setVisible(true);  // add this to show the frame

    ...
}
```

When displaying the dialog, set the parent component to the current `JFrame` so that it gets displayed in the frame itself:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Does it show?");  // add this as parent
}
```